# MATLAB: find peaks from data iterations

Tags: matlab

I have a function that plots the magnitude of an fft function from a signal.

For every iteration I want to determine the x-value of the two peaks below 2000. I thought this was relatively simple using the function `findpeaks` however it has not given me the correct output.

I do not intend to plot the ouput, but just for illustration purposes here is a plot. I only want to know the peaks for the data below 2000 (the first set of peaks)

[image]
Example of one iteration:

[image: example of one iteration]

Here is a bit of my code. B is a vector containing the starting indices for every segment of data that needs to be analysed.

```
function [number] = fourir_(data,sampling_rate)

%Finds the approximate starting index of every peak segment
%B is a vector containing the indeces
[A,B] = findpeaks(double(abs(data) > 0.6), 'MinPeakDistance', 2500); 

Fs = sampling_rate;
t = 0:1/Fs:0.25;

C = zeros(size(B),2)
   for i = 1:numel(B)
    new_data = data(B(i):(B(i)+200))
    y = double(new_data)/max(abs(new_data));
    n = length(y);
    p = abs(fft(y));
    f = (0:n-1)*(Fs/n);

   end
```

Example data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxypn3axoqwo2g0/signal%20%281%29.mat?dl=0

Comment: Can you give some more information on what you mean by "not given me the correct output." What do you get and what did you expect? `findpeaks` will likely get peaks from low level noise, which from your example signal, I'd think you want to filter first. For example, `f(x>2000) = 0;` to get only peaks below 2000 and then `f(f<10) = 0;` to get only major peaks. Then `findpeaks(f)` may work as required? If not, please also post some dummy data for B so people can help.

Comment: @EdSmith as far as I'm aware ````findpeaks```` only takes in data of n*1 format. In this case I've transformed the data so that I get the fourir magnitude plot. Hence when I take ````findpeaks```` from only the values in f, I obviously don't get the values that I want. I've edited my question with the data and the full program so far. I want a matrix with dimensions (number of iterations)*2, in column one the first peak and column 2 the second peak.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `p` based on your variables. I'll add an answer for getting useful peaks which may help but I'm not sure I completely understand...

Comment: @Flo so the solution of Ed Smith should work, just add a threshold no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer, this is exactly what @Ed Smith suggested in his first comment. You can just add a threshold in order to distinguish the major peak.

```
%Finds the approximate starting index of every peak segment
%B is a vector containing the indeces
[A,B] = findpeaks(double(abs(data) > 0.6), 'MinPeakDistance', 2500); 

Fs = sampling_rate;
t = 0:1/Fs:0.25;

C = zeros(size(B),2)
   for i = 1:numel(B)
    new_data = data(B(i):(B(i)+200))
    y = double(new_data)/max(abs(new_data));
    n = length(y);
    p = abs(fft(y));
    f = (0:n-1)*(Fs/n);
    p1 = p(1:round(length(p)/2)); 
    p1(p1<10) = 0; %add a threshold
    [~,ind] = findpeaks(p1); %index of where are the peaks
    C(i,:) = f(ind);
    hold on
    plot(f,p,'b',C(i,:),p(ind),'ro')
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may help, which seems to get the peaks from one fft of your signal data,

```
clear all
close all

%load sample data from https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxypn3axoqwo2g0/signal%20%281%29.mat?dl=0
load('./signal (1).mat')

%get an FFT and take half
p = abs(fft(signal));
p = p(1:length(p)/2);

%find peaks and plot
[pk, loc] = findpeaks(p,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',100,'MINPEAKDISTANCE',100);

plot(p,'k-')
hold all
plot(loc, pk, 'rx')
```

which looks like,

[image]

Where some of the peaks are isolated...

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however this code does not return me all the correct peaks (I think because only p is plotted and it's important to take into account both p and f) and it is important that I have them in order (that is why I added the iteration part, to write them to a matrix). I've added a plot of one iteration to give you a better idea. The function is based on the blog on touch-tone http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/09/01/touch-tone-telephone-dialing/.

Comment: f is simply the sampling vector no ? f doesn't change anything concerning the peak detection ! And have you try to implement the threshold solution ? The first comment of Ed IS the solution !